# javafx 8 compatibility issues - FXML static fields or methods

Tags: java, javafx-2, java-7, java-8, javafx-8

I have designed a javafx application which works fine in jdk 7. When I try to run it in java 8 I am getting the below exceptions:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3132)


Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:364)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:232)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.concurrent.EventHelper.fireEvent(EventHelper.java:219)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.fireEvent(Task.java:1357)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task.setState(Task.java:720)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable$2.run(Task.java:1438)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I found out the reason for this is in the initialize method of the controller class I am not able to use the inbuilt methods in any static component. (For example: staticMyTextField.setText() is causing the problem in java 8 but not in java 7). I am not able to find out anything documented regarding this in the javafx guides. Can someone please provide some ideas on why this is causing an issue in Java 8? And also share documents related to this if any.

Comment: can you provide code sample?

Comment: Please refer this link. This is working in JDK 7 but not in jdk 8                                                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434787/how-to-create-custom-components-in-javafx-2-0-using-fxml....Could you please help?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to inject a `TextField` into a static field. Something like

```
@FXML
private static TextField myTextField ;
```

This apparently worked in JavaFX 2.2. It doesn't work in JavaFX 8. Since no official documentation ever supported this use, it's doesn't really violate backward compatibility, though in fairness the documentation on exactly what the `FXMLLoader` does is pretty woeful.

It doesn't really make much sense to make `@FXML`-injected fields static. When you load an FXML file, it creates new objects for each of the elements in the FXML file. A new controller instance is associated with each call to `FXMLLoader.load(...)` and the fields in that controller *instance* are injected with the corresponding objects created for the FXML elements. So the injected fields are necessarily specific to the controller instance. If you had a static injected fields in the controller, and you loaded the same FXML file twice and displayed it twice in the UI, then you would have no way of referencing both sets of controls.

---

`@FXML` marked static methods referenced from FXML also will not work.

For instance, with:

```
@FXML
private static void changeUser(ActionEvent e) {
    // System.out.println("test");
}
```

And:

```
<Button text="Change User" onAction="#changeUser"/>
```

This will fail with:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#changeUser', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
```

To fix this, just remove the static modifier from the method specifcation.

---

**Update**: Response to question in comments

In particular, don't use static fields just to enable them to be accessible from outside the class. A static field has a single value belonging to the class, instead of a value for each instance of the class, and the decision to make fields static should only be made if that makes sense. In other words, `static` defines *scope*, not *accessibility*. To allow access to instance data, you just have to have a reference to the instance. The `FXMLLoader` has a `getController()` method that allows you to retrieve a reference to the controller.

A related point: it's also not a good idea to expose the UI controls from the controller. You should instead expose the data. For example, instead of defining a `getTextField()` method in the controller, instead define a `textProperty()` method that returns a `StringProperty` representing the contents of the `TextField`. The reason for this is that when your boss comes to the office and tells you he wants the `TextField` to be replaced by a `TextArea`, or a `ComboBox<String>`, or some other control, then it's going to be a lot harder if classes outside of the controller are using your `TextField`. The structure of the data represented by your controller is much less likely to change than the implementation of how that data is presented to the user.

For some examples

- [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)
- [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)
- [JavaFX Data Mangement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118330/javafx-data-mangement/)
- [Access fields from another Controller in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048500/access-fields-from-another-controller-in-javafx/)
- https://github.com/james-d/LeastCommonMultipleCalculator
- https://github.com/james-d/Nested-Controller-Example
- https://github.com/james-d/Dialog-FXML-Example
- https://github.com/james-d/Shared-Data-Controller

Comment: Thanks James..Is there anyway to access a component's content from other controller classes? For example, I have some content(checkboxes and lables) displayed in a listView in one controller class. If I want to access it from another controller class without changing or altering its content how should I do?

Comment: +1 for a good explanation.  I always thought static made sense in these situations. You could still use static as late as [8b109](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21502430/2855515).  This is about the 5th question I've seen on this so far, but never an explanation of 'why not static'.