# java.lang.NullPointerException in handling with controls between 2 controllers - Javafx

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, controller, fxml

I've been trying button events between 2 scenes in Javafx.

This is Start.fxml (in view package):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="292.0" prefWidth="383.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="controller.StartController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="lbl1" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="209.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt1" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="209.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="191.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn1Click" text="Click" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is Preserences.fxml (in view package):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="292.0" prefWidth="383.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="controller.PreferencesController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="lbl2" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="209.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="txt2" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="209.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="191.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btn2Click" text="Click" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is Main.fxml which is like a container for the previous 2 files.(in view package):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="481.0" prefWidth="468.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <TabPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="481.0" prefWidth="468.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Start">
               <content>
                  <fx:include source="Start.fxml" />
               </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Preferences">
               <content>
                  <fx:include source="Preferences.fxml" />
               </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is StartController.java (in controller package):

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class StartController implements Initializable {

    @FXML public static Label lbl1;
    @FXML public static TextField txt1;
    @FXML public static Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @FXML private void btn1Click(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Button 1 clicked");
        lbl1.setText(PreferencesController.txt2.getText());
    }

}
```

This is PreferencesController.java (in controller package):

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class PreferencesController implements Initializable {

    @FXML public static Label lbl2;
    @FXML public static TextField txt2;
    @FXML public static Button btn2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @FXML private void btn2Click(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Button 2 clicked");
        lbl2.setText(StartController.txt1.getText());
    }

}
```

This is MainController.java (in controller package):

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class MainController implements Initializable{

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    }

}
```

Finally, this is Main.java in application package:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But when I clicked the buttons, it gives me the errors:

```
"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.StartController.btn1Click(StartController.java:26)
    ... 61 more"
```

Please help me! :(

Comment: You can't declare `@FXML`-injected fields as static. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields/23109125#23109125

Answer (score 2):

OK so the NPE is being thrown on this line:

```
    lbl1.setText(PreferencesController.txt2.getText());
```

At the basic Java level, are only two ways that you could get that to happen:

- when `lnl1` is `null`, or
- when `PreferencesController.txt2` is `null`.

No other explanations are possible ... given that `PreferencesController.txt2` is a static field.

---

I'm not familiar with JavaFX or FXML, but I suspect that your mistake is declaring the fields as `static`.  I suspect that this causes the FXML mechanisms to not inject the reference to the UI component correctly.  So those variables remain as `null` ... and you get an NPE.

Confirmation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109125/139985.  (Thanks for the link @James_D)

Comment: upvoted because it is the correct answer. Its not possible to inject FXML static fields.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation (and the vote, though that's less important).