# JavaFX static/non static with Controllers

Tags: java, javafx

I've tried to make a little math program with JavaFX. I have a `Button` action in Controller 1:

```
@FXML
public void showCalc(ActionEvent event2) {
    layout.parabel_nullstelle_showCalc.setVariables(a, b, c, x1, x2, ze1, ze2, ze3, ze4, ze5, ze6, ze7);
    Parent root3 = main.Main.getParent();
    Scene showCalc = new Scene(root3, 500, 1000);
    Stage paranullCalc = new Stage();
    paranullCalc.setTitle("Rechung");
    paranullCalc.setScene(showCalc);
    paranullCalc.show();
}
```

It opens a new `Stage` with `Scene` which contains a calculation.
In the Controller for the `showCalc` I have the set variables method.

```
public static void setVariables(double a1, double b1, double c1,double x11, double x22, double ze11, double ze22, double ze33, double ze44, double ze55, double ze66, double ze77){
    a = (float) a1;
    b = (float) b1;
    c = (float) c1;
    x1 = (float) x11;
    x2 = (float) x22;
    ze1 = (float) ze11;
    ze2 = (float) ze22;
    ze3 = (float) ze33;
    ze4 = (float) ze44;
    ze5 = (float) ze55;
    ze6 = (float) ze66;
    ze7 = (float) ze77;
}
```

I needed to make it static because I can't do an object of a controller and with import I get the static/non static error. But now I want to change the text of a `TextArea` in the same `Scene` as the `setVariables`, so I can show the calculation. I can't make the `TextArea` static, because then it crashes. I also can't access it without static and creating an object of itself also isn't a solution. So how do I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the code for `main.Main.getParent();`? or the declaration  for `main.Main`.

Comment: It's not necessary, it just gets the Parent out of the Main Class because you can only import fxml in the start method, nothing interesting (it just returns the Parent)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't do an object of a controller" and "you can only import FXML in the start method"? It is (almost?) always a mistake to make fields and methods in a controller static.

Comment: I can only do example = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("example")); in the start method of the Application, not in a Controller. And if I dont set setVariables to static, I get an error in showCalc, it says "Non static method setVariables(*) cannot be refernced from a static context", and creating an object of the controller also isn't working.

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you mean by that comment. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields/23109125#23109125) help at all.

Comment: Sry, pressed Enter and it sent, i dont often write anything here

Comment: Why can you not load the second FXML from the controller?

Comment: I think i got the loading to work, but this wasn't the Problem, the posts in the two links are a bit complicatet (English is my second language), but is there a simple way to set the content of the TextArea from another class?

Answer (score 2):

Don't make variables or methods in your controller `static` solely for the purpose of being able to access them from elsewhere. It rarely, if ever, makes sense to have `static` members in a controller.

To access a method in a controller, just retrieve the controller instance from the `FXMLLoader`. You haven't really posted enough code to provide a complete answer, but you need to do something like:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("calc.fxml"));
Parent calcRoot = loader.load();
CalcController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setVariables(...);
Scene showCalc = new Scene(calcRoot, 500, 1000);
// ...
```

and remove `static` from the `setVariables` method declaration in the controller class.

Comment: This looks like it could work, but when I click in the Programm on the Button which opens it, I get an Error: http://pastebin.com/M1fabch6

Comment: You cannot get that error from the code I posted. It says you are trying to assign a grid pane to an `FXMLLoader`. What is on line 77 of parabel_nullstelle_layout.java?

Comment: Its the First line of the method (http://pastebin.com/Sr93buMR), so the line with "throws Expection", IntelIJ said I should use IOExpection which also didnt work, so I tried this. (I'm a bit new to Java, so I don't know what this is)

Comment: Why are you doing `FXMLLoader loader = FXMLLoader.load(...)`? Why not use the code I showed above?

Comment: My bad, already wrote the line a few minutes before and didn't change it, now it works, thanks!

Comment: You dont need to load the Parent to access the function of the controller.