# java.lang.NullPointerException for static button in JavaFX with static reference

Tags: java, javafx, cron, quartz

Okay so I have a bit a conundrum. I have a Qaurtz Cron that I want to use to schedule and run some Java Tests. These task are scheduled through a gui that Uses JavaFX. However, the job itself calls a run tests method. The job forces me to make certain elements static, but by making them static, I get a null pointer exception. I would really appreciate some help here.

So here is the job class that forces things to be static.

```
public class newJob implements Job{

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("We are attempting the job now");
        try {
            FXMLDocumentController.runScheduledTests();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my controller I have something like this:

```
public static void runTests() throws SQLException, IOException {
        // Set running to true. In current form we do not use this bool,
        // however, we may
        // make changes that rely on this.
        running = true;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        // Verify that users exist, and there is a url with the word max in it
        int count = DBHelpers.getResults("SELECT * FROM USERS;", new String[] { "ID" }).length();

        // Verify that we have both users and a maximo url to work with.
        if ((!userList.isEmpty() || count > 0) && userMaxListChoice.length() > 5) {

            // Set the proper driver, default to chrome if none is selected
            if (IEbutton.isSelected()) {
                BrowserConfig.setDriver(Browsers.IE());
            } else {
                BrowserConfig.setDriver(Browsers.Chrome());
            }

            // Let's assign maximo. If no one has clicked the use UserList
            // button, assume that the data inside
            // maximo name is good to use
            if (userMaxListChoice != null) {
                BrowserConfig.setMaximo(userMaxListChoice);
                // System.out.println("used maxLIst choice");
            } else {
                // If the user has not selected a name from the maximo list,
                // let's grab whatever
                // they have entered in the maximoName field.
                BrowserConfig.setMaximo(maximoName.getText());
            }

            // Set the system pause based on the interval string
            int pause = Integer.parseInt(interval.getText().toString());
            // Make sure the puase is in miliseconds
            pause = pause * 1000;
            BrowserConfig.setInterval(pause);
```

Note that the runScheduledTests() methods does some configuring and calls the runTest method. Inside the run test method is where I'm hitting the error specifically this line:

```
if (IEbutton.isSelected()) {
                BrowserConfig.setDriver(Browsers.IE());
            } else {
                BrowserConfig.setDriver(Browsers.Chrome());
            }
```

The reason is that above I have this :

```
@FXML
    public static RadioButton ChromeButton;

    @FXML
    public static RadioButton IEbutton;
```

As I said this is a bit of an issue, If I don't make them static the job class yells at me for making a non-static reference.

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: Why can't you create an instance of your controller instead of using `FXMLDocumentController.runScheduledTests();` ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would do that. Nor am I sure how that would turn out. I really only want to execute the FXMLDocumentController.runScheduledTests() method from the job anyway. The controller has other methods and logic that I don't want to execute.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can make the FXMLController or the Job Class a singleton.

Comment: From the name of `FXMLDocumentController` I am assuming that it is a controller to an FXML document. If yes, then you could just load the FXML using a [FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) and then fetch the controller instance from it.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, do you have an example? I am unsure how to do that. Could you post an example of doing that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, but before I do that, can you add a snippet of the FXML that has the `fx:controller` defined in it in the question?

Comment: Just a moment. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR : You shouldn't use static on the fields annotated with @FXML.

For more information go through - [javafx 8 compatibility issues - FXML static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109125/1759128)

You could load the FXML by using the FXMLLoader and then get an instance of the controller from it. By doing this, you can convert the method `runScheduledTests()` into a non-static method.

```
public class newJob implements Job{

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = 
                        new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path-to-fxml.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.load();
            FXMLDocumentController fxmlDocumentController = 
                        (FXMLDocumentController)fxmlLoader.getController();
            fxmlDocumentController.runScheduledTests(); // convert the method to non-static
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got an the follow error: 
org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'nextJob.cronJob', because one already exists with this identification

Comment: I managed to get it two work, but I did have to edit my initialize method to make handle two different calls to initialize since the second call caused some variables to change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use static when the controller itself is not static. Take into consideration I recommend taking a look at the difference between static and non-static [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-vs-non-static-methods/). In regards to fixing your code. First make your buttons `ChromeButton` and `IEbutton` not static. Then when your application class, something like this:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //pass a reference of your stage to job.
    }
}
```

Then Pass a reference of your buttons or controller into the Job class as a variable. Like this:

```
public class newJob implements Job{

  private RadioButton chrome;
  private RadioButton ie;

  public newJob(RadioButton chrome, RadioButton ie) {
    this.chrome = chrome;
    this.ie = ie;
  }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("We are attempting the job now");
        try {
            FXMLDocumentController.runScheduledTests();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The core of your problem is controller variables **CANNOT** be static as the controller is dependent on instantiating the class and passing the required information in. The best way to fix this is by passing a reference either to the buttons or the class by using variables in the constructor. Please read the link I sent you to get a better understanding between static and non-static. Also, if you are confused about constructors take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) as well.

Comment: could you edit this and show what an example of passing a reference of the stage could look like. I've only been using JavaFX for like 2 weeks. This is still kind of new to me. Otherwise I think this might work.

Comment: Do you have a github for your code? Or could you [gist](https://gist.github.com) your relevant code?

Comment: The files are pretty large. the FXMLController is something like 1200 lines. What information would you need to so I can make sure to just share the important stuff and save you time.

Comment: its fine. gist it all.

Comment: Here is the gist [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/28bb034dc1b0d5a4a0cf987cf7688944)

Comment: It does not. I tried the other solution posted with no luck.