# How can I initialize ListView from FXML file?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have my scene made with JavaFX Scene Builder and ListView in it. I want it to show some data from xml file, but I have no idea how to properly initialize this ListView.

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import application.Cparsing;
import javafx.collections.*;

public class MainDriversController{
    private static ListView<String> driversLV;
    static ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void SetListView(){
        for(int x=0; x<Cparsing.driversNodes.getLength(); x++) {
            observableList.add(Cparsing.driversNodes.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("nick").getNodeValue());
        }
    driversLV.setItems(observableList);
    System.out.println(driversLV);
    }
}
```

That of course gives me NullPointerException because it's not initialized. 
I've tried to add

```
driversLV = new ListView<String>(observableList);
```

and no error then, but ListView is still empty in GUI.

```
System.out.println(driversLV);
```

gives:

```
ListView@54f2d1d5[styleClass=list-view]
```

So my question is: what is the proper way to initialize ListView? Is my code correct despite this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't make anything here static. The controller is an *object* associated with the UI loaded from the FXML file, so the fields and methods need to be member of that object, not of the class. (And the `FXMLLoader` [will not initialize static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields/23109125#23109125).)

Second, annotate the fields declared in the FXML file with `@FXML`. That will allow the `FXMLLoader` to initialize them even if you declare them private (which you should do). Make sure the `fx:id` assigned to the control in the FXML file is the same as the field name.

Finally, the `FXMLLoader` will (by default) create an instance of your controller class by calling its no-argument constructor, then it will initialize the fields. Consequently, of course, they will not be initialized when the constructor is invoked. Instead, use the `initialize()` method, which the `FXMLLoader` will invoke automatically once the `@FXML`-annotated fields have been injected.

So you should have

```
public class MainDriversController{

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> driversLV;

    private ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        for(int x=0; x<Cparsing.driversNodes.getLength(); x++) {
            observableList.add(Cparsing.driversNodes.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("nick").getNodeValue());
        }
        driversLV.setItems(observableList);
        System.out.println(driversLV);
    }
}
```

And of course your FXML file will have `fx:controller="my.package.name.MainDriversController"` in the root element, and

```xml
<ListView fx:id="driversLV" />
```

as an element somewhere.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaank you! Was trying many methods since yesterday and it was just the initialize() method! :)

Comment: And you can make the Controller implement `javafx.fxml.Initializable`

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta Why though? The `Initializable` interface was replaced with automatic calling of the `initialize()` method many years ago. You can still use the interface, for back-compatibility reasons, but why would you when there are more modern alternatives?

Comment: Yes. But I find it less magic and more explicit that way... It's a question of personal preference.

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta The flip side is that with the "modern" approach you can make the `initialize()` method `private`, if you annotate it `@FXML`. Making it private makes sense from an encapsulation perspective. The annotation takes away some of the "magic". I'll update this (old) answer to show that approach.

Comment: OK, it's good to know.