# Label's SetText JavaFX not working

Tags: java, javafx, label

The problem is label's setText() is not woking. It happens when the scene shows up, but the initial label text doesn't change. My setText label won't work when I run the code. What can I do? Is this a wrong logic?

Main Class:

```
   package Main;

public class MainMenu extends Application {
    public static String t = "ебучий лейбл";
    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//          test_timer.setText("lalala");
            System.out.print("dwdw");
        }
    }

    public static Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
    Timer myTimer;
//    @FXML
//    public static Label test_timer;
    @FXML
    Label test_timer = new Label();
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
//        MainMenuController.language_chg = "ru";
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../f_XML/Menu.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Localization.Locate", locale));
//      fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Localization.Locate", locale(MainMenuController.language_chg)));

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        fxmlLoader.getController();
        test_timer.setText("dwdwdwdwdwd");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720 );
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();        

        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@FXML
    public static Label test_timer = new Label();

    public void btnActionLanguage(ActionEvent actionEvent) {     
        test_timer.setText("вв");    
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        test_timer.setText("Putin is God,Navalniy loh");
    }
```

FXML:

```
<HBox focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@../Stylesheets/StyleMenu.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.MainMenuController">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="955.0" styleClass="foreground1" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <HBox.margin>
            <Insets left="240.0" right="240.0" />
         </HBox.margin>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="panel_1" prefHeight="179.0" prefWidth="800.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="23.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="23.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="325.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="325.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="23.0">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../images/logo.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label fx:id="test_timer" layoutX="76.0" layoutY="111.0" text="00:00" />
                  <Label layoutX="694.0" layoutY="23.0" opacity="0.35" text="v.0.1.3.alpha" textFill="#aa00ff" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="111.0" prefWidth="800.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btnNewWorld" layoutX="244.0" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#new_world" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="312.0" styleClass="btn_1" text="%MainMenu.newGame" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutX="244.0" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="312.0" styleClass="btn_1" text="%MainMenu.continueGame" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutX="244.0" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="69.0" prefWidth="312.0" styleClass="btn_1" text="%MainMenu.settingsGame" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="90.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutX="244.0" layoutY="56.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnActionExit" prefHeight="69.0" prefWidth="312.0" styleClass="btn_1" text="%Main.exitGame" textFill="WHITE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="244.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="24.0" />
                     </font>
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnActionLanguage" prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="62.0" styleClass="language_btn" text="en" textFill="#fff8f8">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

I have no idea why setText() does not work. Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you clean up the code before posting it? Are we supposed to be looking at the lines that are commented out, or not? You have two calls to `setText(...)`: which one are we supposed to help you diagnose? And you seem to have a lot of code that was apparently randomly added to try and fix the problem, but didn't (what is the point of `fxmlLoader.getController()`, for example?). Two things: 1. It never makes sense to initialize a field annotated `@FXML`; remove those initializations. 2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields

Comment: Thank you, bro! Problem was in static