# problem with setvalue to label in JAVA fx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a function:

```
    public static void printOnLable(String str){
    try {
        labelAkcja.textProperty().setValue(str);
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        System.err.println("Cause = " + e.getCause());
    }
}
```

but when i want to call it

```
Controller.printOnLable("server started");
```

I get always an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvdYt.png)

Comment: Either `labelAkcja` or `textProperty()` are null. Make sure they aren't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Amongalen just a note: the property is never null, its value might, though not a problem here :)

Comment: ye, this one is my

Comment: @kleopatra We can't really be sure what `labelAkcja` is, it could be of some class that OP created :)

Comment: @Amongalen whatever it is, if it allows a property to be null its API is severely broken :)

Comment: Reasonably good chance (making some guesses about the different roles of members in the code snippet) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields is also relevant.