# Root cannot be null exception with multiple FXML/Controller in JavaFX

Tags: java, exception, javafx, fxml

I'm working on a JavaFX project to manage workouts. While it had one big .fxml file, and one big MainController class, it worked fine:

WorkoutsMain.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="workouts.WorkoutsMainController">
    <children>
        <SplitPane fx:id="splitPane" dividerPositions="0.15" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane>
                    <children>
                        <StackPane fx:id="menuPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"/>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane>
                    <children>
                        <Pane fx:id="statisticsPane" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="130.0"/>
                        <Pane fx:id="workoutsPane" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="130.0">
                        //... other FX elements
                        </Pane>
                        <Pane fx:id="calendarPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="130.0"/>
                        <StackPane fx:id="logoPane" onMouseClicked="#setLogo" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="778.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"/>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

WorkoutsMainController.java:

```
public class WorkoutsMainController implements Initializable, SplitPaneDividerController {
    private final DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
    private boolean first = true;
    private String logoName;
    @FXML
    private StackPane logoPane, menuPane;
    private final List<Pane> panes = new ArrayList<>();
    @FXML
    private Pane calendarPane, workoutsPane, statisticsPane;
    @FXML
    private SplitPane splitPane;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane;
    // methods and functions
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        setLogo();
        disableSplitPaneDivider(splitPane, 0.1525);
        setUpMainMenu();
    }
}
```

MainClass.java:

```
public class MainClass extends Application {
    private Parent anchorPane;
    private final String fxml = "WorkoutsMain.fxml";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {       
        try {
            anchorPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error when trying to load " + fxml);
          }
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/calendarIconWhite.png")));
        stage.setTitle("THE WORKOUT CALENDAR 1.7.0 by hazazs®");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Then I wanted to cut a piece from the WorkoutsMain.fxml. I have changed a segment in the original big .fxml file like this:
from

```
<Pane fx:id="workoutsPane" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="130.0">
    //... other FX elements
</Pane>
```

to

```
<fx:include source="Workouts.fxml" fx:id="workoutsPane"/>
```

Then I have created a new fxml file with its own Controller class:
Workouts.fxml:

```
<Pane fx:id="workoutsPane" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="130.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="workouts.WorkoutsController">
// other FX elements
</Pane>
```

I have created an appropriate WorkoutsController class and I have changed my WorkoutsMainController like this:

```
public class WorkoutsMainController implements Initializable, SplitPaneDividerController {
    protected static final DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
    private final WorkoutsController workoutsController = new WorkoutsController();
    private boolean first = true;
    private String logoName;
    @FXML
    private StackPane logoPane, menuPane;
    private final List<Pane> panes = new ArrayList<>();
    @FXML
    private Pane calendarPane, workoutsPane, statisticsPane;
    @FXML
    protected static SplitPane splitPane;
    @FXML
    protected static AnchorPane anchorPane;
    // and so on..
```

But from now I get Exception when I try to start my application:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:336)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:194)
    at workouts.MainClass.start(MainClass.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

Any suggestion guys, what should I do to make this work once again? With one .fxml and one Controller it worked perfectly.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new `WorkoutsController` instance in your `WorkoutsMainController`, instead of using the one created for you by the `FXMLLoader`. The `@FXML`-annotated fields in the instance you create will all be null, so you are probably getting a null pointer exception somewhere. (You should be seeing the "Error when trying to load WorkoutsMain.fxml" message in the console.) Thus `anchorPane` in your `start()` method is never initialized and you get an exception when you pass the null `anchorPane` reference to the `Scene` constructor.

Note also you have (for some unknown reason) made `splitPane` and `anchorPane` `static`: it makes no sense to do that, and the `FXMLLoader` will not initialize static fields. So those fields are also null in the controller.

If you don't squash exceptions thrown by loading the FXML, you will be able to see the actual stack trace for the underlying exception.

The fixes are:

1. don't make `@FXML`-annotated fields `static`. See [javafx 8 compatibility issues - FXML static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields)
2. To inject the actual controller instance for the included FXML that is created by the `FXMLLoader`, see [Nested Controllers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) in the documentation. In short, since your `fx:include` has `fx:id="workoutsPane"`, you should replace

   ```
    private final WorkoutsController workoutsController = new WorkoutsController();
   ```

   with

   ```
    @FXML private WorkoutsController workoutsPaneController ;
   ```

   (and replace all occurrences of `workoutsController` with `workoutsPaneController` in the remainder of `WorkoutsMainController`).

Comment: It works, you are amazing, thank you. The reason for the static fields: they are in the WorkoutsMain.fxml, so that they has to be declared in the WorkoutsMainController. But I have to use them in the WorkoutsController class, so I just wanted to "share" them without instantiate them. Should I use getters in order to use these two fields in WorkoutsController?

Comment: @tibotka `static` is about scope, not about ability to see something. That comment really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Then how can I use @FXML items declared in the WorkoutsMainController in the WorkoutsController?

Comment: @tibotka Generally, it's bad practice to share UI controls outside the controller in which they're declared. You should share the data instead. But if you really want to do this, just pass a reference to the `WorkoutsMainController` instance to the `WorkoutsController`.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly due to my low reputation I can't upvote your answer and comments.