# Changing JavaFX-Label Text in an small Client - Server Application

Tags: java, javafx, network-programming, udp, client-server

Ive created a small client-server prorgramm which works as following: A Client sents all five seconds a random number to a server which sends then sends a (more or less famous) quote back to the client. The random number represents the index of the ArrayList in the ServerClass in which some quotes are located. The connection works well and the clients receives the quotes and i can easily print them out with sysout.
My Problem is now that i wanna display the received Quote as a Label in a small JavaFX / FXML File and the text should change every five seconds when a new quote comes in from the Server.
The Class QuotesClient (so the Client) is also the Controller of the corresponding FXML file but the Problem is since that the method in my Client class which is responsible for handling the incoming UDP Packets is static and of course i cant access the non-static Label in this method.

Ive tried to make the Label static as well but then i receive a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Aufgabe1.QuotesClient.main(QuotesClient.java:48)
    at Aufgabe1.QuotesApp.lambda$1(QuotesApp.java:32)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Here is my ClientFile:

```
public class QuotesClient {
    private static final int BUFSIZE = 508;
    
    @FXML
    private static Label zitatLabel; //Thats the quoteLabel i wanna change

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        var host = "localhost";
        var localPort = 40000;
        var serverPort = 50000; 
        try (var socket = new DatagramSocket(localPort)) {
            while(true) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomNumber = random.nextInt(3);
                System.out.println("Die Zufallszahl ist: " + randomNumber);
                var data = serialize(randomNumber).getBytes();
                
                //Send packages (random number for the server)
                var addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                var packetOut = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, addr, serverPort);
                socket.send(packetOut);
                
                //Receive packeges (Quote-Objekts)
                var packetIn = new DatagramPacket(new byte[BUFSIZE], BUFSIZE);
                socket.receive(packetIn);
                
                var json = new String(packetIn.getData());
                Quote quote = deserialize(json);
                System.out.println("Quote: " + quote.getText());
                zitatLabel.setText(quote.getText()); //Throws the NullPointerException
               
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static String serialize(int number) {
        var jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        return jsonb.toJson(number);
    }
    
    private static Quote deserialize(String data) {
        var jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        return jsonb.fromJson(data, Quote.class);
    }
    
}
```

I start my whole Programm via the QuotesApp.java Class. Ive also created two seperate Threads, one for the server and one for the client:

```
public class QuotesApp extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(QuotesApp.class.getResource("/Aufgabe1/GUIQuotes.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("UserLogin");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        
        // Starte den Server und den Client in separaten Threads
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            QuotesServer.main(new String[0]);
        });

        Thread clientThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
            QuotesClient.main(new String[0]);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        serverThread.start();
        clientThread.start();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fields annotated `@FXML` are initialized *in the controller* when the `FXMLLoader` loads an FXML file. The controller is a specific object that is created by the `FXMLLoader`. It only makes sense to try to access those fields from within that specific object. Since `FXML`-annotated fields are only initialized in the specific instances of the controller class created by the `FXMLLoader`, it really doesn't make sense to annotate `static` fields with `@FXML`, and such fields will never be initialized. See also [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105433/javafx-8-compatibility-issues-fxml-static-fields-or-methods).

In your case, your server and client are not even represented by objects (since they just use static methods, which by definition are not part of any object). You first need to write this in an object-oriented fashion with the server and client represented by actual objects. Then you need to design the UI part of the application so the UI can be updated by changes in values from the client; a MVC-like approach is usually the best way to do this.

Here is a quick example. I used Jackson for the JSON [de]serializing and plain sockets and server sockets as I know those technologies better. The same structure can be used with different underlying technologies.

First, here is the `Quote` class, implemented simply as a `record`:

`Quote.java`:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public record Quote(String text, String author) {

    @JsonCreator
    public Quote(@JsonProperty("text") String text, @JsonProperty("author") String author) {
        this.text = text;
        this.author = author;
    }

}
```

Here is a `QuoteServer`. This has a `serveQuotes()` method which blocks indefinitely (at least, until the server is closed) and hands off handling requests to an executor. The requests simply send an `int` representing which quote they want (in a real application you would handle invalid quote ids, etc):

`QuoteServer.java`

```
package org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class QuoteServer implements AutoCloseable{

    public static final int PORT = 5555;

    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    private final List<Quote> quotes = List.of(
            new Quote(
                """
                    There are only two ways to live your life.
                    One is as though nothing is a miracle.
                    The other is as though everything is a miracle.
                    """,
                    "Albert Einstein"),
            new Quote(
                """
                    Good judgment comes from experience, and experience comes from bad judgment.
                    """,
                    "Rita Mae Brown"
            ),
            new Quote(
                """
                    Imagination was given to man to compensate him for what he is not,
                    and a sense of humor was provided to console him for what he is.
                    """,
            "Oscar Wilde"
            )
    );

    public QuoteServer() throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }

    public void serveQuotes() {
        try {
            while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                exec.execute(() -> handleRequest(socket));
            }
        } catch (SocketException sockExc) {
            if (serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Socket closed");
            } else {
                sockExc.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void handleRequest(Socket socket) {
        try {
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int index = input.readInt();
            Quote quote = quotes.get(index);
            objectMapper.writeValue(socket.getOutputStream(), quote);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        exec.shutdown();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Here is a `QuoteClient` class. This just has a one-shot method, taking an `int` and returning a `Quote` that is sent from the server. Again, in real life you might add more functionality.

`QuoteClient.java`

```
package org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class QuoteClient {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public Quote getQuote(int index) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", QuoteServer.PORT);
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            output.writeInt(index);
            Quote quote = objectMapper.readValue(socket.getInputStream(), Quote.class);
            socket.close();
            return quote;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

For the UI part, use some kind of Model-View-Controller (MVC) or similar approach. The most important aspect of this is to separate out the data that is displayed in the application into a model class, and let the view update by observing the model. (The different flavors of MVC differ by how this is divided up between the view and controller.)

In this case, the model gets its data from the server, so it needs a client. To update on a regular basis (every five seconds, for example), you can use a `ScheduledService` that creates `Task`s that request data via the client. The service's `lastValueProperty()` holds the last value returned from a task, i.e. the last value retrieved from the server. So the model can simply look like:

`Model.java`

```
package org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

public class Model {

    private final QuoteClient quoteClient = new QuoteClient();
    private final ScheduledService<Quote> service;

    public Model() {
        service = new ScheduledService<>() {
            private final Random rng = new Random();
            @Override
            protected Task<Quote> createTask() {
                final int quoteIndex = rng.nextInt(3);
                return new Task<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Quote call() {
                        return quoteClient.getQuote(quoteIndex);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));
        service.start();

    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Quote> currentQuoteProperty() {
        return service.lastValueProperty();
    }

}
```

Here is a simple FXML file. It just has some labels (including one for the quote's text and one for its author):

`Quotes.fxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver.QuoteController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Label fx:id="quoteLabel"/>
    <HBox spacing="5"><Label text=" - "/><Label fx:id="authorLabel" /></HBox>
</VBox>
```

Here is the corresponding controller. It needs access to the model, so it has a `setModel(Model model)` method. When it receives a new model, it just binds the label's text to values in the model:

`QuoteController.java`

```
package org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class QuoteController {

   @FXML
   private Label quoteLabel ;
   @FXML
   private Label authorLabel;
   public void setModel(Model model) {
       quoteLabel.textProperty().bind(model.currentQuoteProperty().map(Quote::text));
       authorLabel.textProperty().bind(model.currentQuoteProperty().map(Quote::author));
   }
}
```

And finally the application class. This starts a server in the `init()` method (which you probably wouldn't do in real life; the server would not be in the same JVM) and runs it in a background thread. It also creates a `Model`. The model is passed to the controller after loading the FXML.

`QuoteApplication.java`

```
package org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class QuoteApplication extends Application {

    private Model model;
    private QuoteServer server ;

    @Override
    public void init() throws IOException {
        server = new QuoteServer();
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(server::serveQuotes);
        serverThread.setDaemon(true);
        serverThread.start();
        model = new Model();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(QuoteApplication.class.getResource("Quotes.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 500);
        QuoteController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.setModel(model);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        server.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Finally, for completeness, my `module-info.java`:

```
module org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

    opens org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver;
}
```

and `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jamesd.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>quoteserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>quoteserver</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver/org.jamesd.examples.quoteserver.QuoteApplication
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```